# Remix have access to whole system, not just the shared directory

Tags: command-line-interface, ethereum, solidity, cryptocurrency, remix

When running the remixd plugin deamon process, even though I set the shared folder parameter, the Remix IDE has access, via browser, to my whole system, instead of just the specified folder. Is this a bug?

```
➜  ~ remixd -s /some/shared/folder/                                 
[WARN] You can only connect to remixd from one of the supported origins.
[WARN] Any application that runs on your computer can potentially read from and write to all files in the directory.
[WARN] Symbolic links are not forwarded to Remix IDE

Wed Feb 03 2021 22:03:29 GMT+0100 (CET) Remixd is listening on 127.0.0.1:65520
[WARN] You may now only use IDE at https://remix.ethereum.org to connect to that instance
setup notifications for /some/shared/folder/
```

Answer (score 0):

I was correct - there was a bug in the current version. To fix, you have to execute:

```
npm uninstall -g remixd
npm install -g @remix-project/remixd
```